Flutter Best Pattern for Fixed and Scrollable Sections
I have used pages with fixed and scrollable sections previously and always struggled and have used trial and error, probably not resulting in the best solution. This time I decided to research and hopefully find the correct way, so I wrote a small test program to slightly emulate my app.
The components used are essentially:
   Scaffold:
       body: Column
           Widgets
           Expanded
                child: RawScrollbar
                    child: SingleChildScrollView
                        child: Row
                            children: Column
                                children: Widgets

That appears to me to be one solution to the problem. It seems a lot of Widgets, but if that’s the best solution, then once one knows it, that’s it.
My question is, is there a better way to solve this?
My test app is below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage();
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePage();
}

class _MyHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScrollController _wScrollController = ScrollController();
  final TextStyle _wStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue);
  //
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _wScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text('Scrolling Test'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          SizedBox(height: 100, child: Text('Page Heading', style: _wStyle)),
          Icon(Icons.directions_boat_filled_rounded,
              size: 100, color: Colors.blue),
          SizedBox(height: 25),
          Text(style: _wStyle, "Select Option"),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Expanded(
              child: RawScrollbar(
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  thumbColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  thickness: 12,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
                  minThumbLength: 100,
                  scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                  controller: _wScrollController,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      primary: false,
                      controller: _wScrollController,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children:
                                  _fnCreateButtons(10) /* LIST OF BUTTONS */,
                            )
                          ]))))
        ]));
  }

  //==== FUNCTION - CREATE LIST OF BUTTONS ====//
  List<Widget> _fnCreateButtons(int iCount) {
    List<Widget> lswButtons = [];
    for (int iNdx = 0; iNdx < iCount; iNdx++) {
      lswButtons.add(SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Selection ${iNdx + 1}'))));
    }
    return lswButtons;
  }
}



maybe you are using 2 scrollable widgets in a single screen.have you tried the sliver_appbar.

I think your solution looks good.
Except for one point. I would prefer to use ListView.builder rather than SingleChildScrollView. ListView.builder is good at building items to display when they are needed. SingleChildScrollView builds all the items at once.  It's okay for creating 10 buttons, but if you have to create 1000 buttons then it will be a performance issue.
Adding RawScrollbar is a great solution from a UI/UX perspective
